# How to access parent component state in child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router(v3) for routing purpose in my app. I have some nested route and want to access parent component state in child component.

**Route:**

```
<Route component={Main}>
   <Route path="home" component={Home} />
</Route>
```

**Main Component(parent):**

```
export default class Main extends Component {
  constructor(prop){
    super(prop);
    this.state = {
      user : {}
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        Main component
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Home Component(child):**

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(prop){
    super(prop);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        Main component
        want to access user data here. how to access user from parent component?
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In `Home` component i want to access user data, that is in parent component `Main`. Is there any way to access parent component state in child component ?

Comment: the proper way of doing this would be by passing `state` as `props` to Home component or In your parent, you can create a function like `addUser` which will do the required `setState` and then pass that function as `props` to the child component.

Answer (score 12):

Your problem is that you can't just pass `user` as props to `Home` because `App` is not direcly rendering `Home`. You're doing that through `React-Router`.

You got 2 approaches here:

1. Use a state management solution like `Redux` and `connect()` both `Main` and `Home` to the `user` in store. This way, `user` is not part of `Main` state, but part of the app store and can be accessed from other components. This is the most sophisticated / extensible solution.
2. Use [Contexts](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html). From the docs: *In some cases, you want to pass data through the component tree without having to pass the props down manually at every level. You can do this directly in React with the powerful "context" API.* If you want to avoid using Redux or Mobx or any state management this may be the way to go.

Comment: Contexts - exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

send state of parent component as props to child component.
within Parent component fetch child like this...

```
<Home user={this.state.user} />
```

Access user in child by `this.props.user`